# Open prepopulated SQLite database in Cordova (for android) and Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, sqlite, cordova

I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 and the Cordova Tools package.

I have most of my app working, and I'm now ready to add the DB logic.  I have a DB full of quotes, and I need to tie that into the app.

Following this link:  [adding dynamic data with SQLite](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-05-28/adding-dynamic-data-with-the-sqlite-plugin)

I was able to get SQLite to talk to a DB ([using the sqlitePlugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin))  However, I can't figure out how to use a pre-populated DB.  It always created a new empty DB.  I've found several articles on the web that keep saying "put the db in the www folder"... but the Cordova project doesn't have a www folder.

Putting the SQLite DB file in the root doesn't work, and I tried using a path and putting it in a sub-dir.  No luck there either.

Has anyone been able to make this work?

Comment: Should it be the 'assets/www' directory? http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: There isn't an assets/www directory in the Visual Studio system.  I think VS masks some of the folders.... :(

Comment: See my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673365/working-with-prepopulated-sqlite-database-in-phonegap-android/37857340#37857340

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question, but I will answer to serve as a reference: I solved this problem by changing the plugin. Previously, I was using plugin `cordova-sqlite-storage` (https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage), but it doesn't copy the prepopulated database. It always creates an empty one.

After days of fighting, I uninstalled the plugin and installed this one: `cordova-plugin-sqlite` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sqlite). This one works like a charm, it will copy the DB in the www folder to the device. Just follow the instructions and don't forget the `createFromLocation` parameter.

The strange bit it that both plugins are from the same author, and both seem to be active projects. Go figure.

Comment: cordova-plugin-sqlite is "Deprecated"

Answer (score 1):

> Old question, but I will answer to serve as a reference (2)!

Pre-populated SQLite is supported by [cordova-sqlite-ext](https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext) project.

The steps are simple:

- put the database file in the **www** directory and open the database like: www/sample.db

Then, use:

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "sample.db", createFromLocation: 1});
```

More information: https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext#pre-populated-databases

Many sites and answers point to use Cordova-sqlite-storage for this. In fact, this feature was in this project, but it was moved to Cordova-sqlite-ext (they are from the same creator).

I don't recomend using cordova-plugin-sqlite. It is deprecated.