# Cordova/Ionic pre populated SQLite database issue

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

So I have a Ionic app I want to deploy with pre populated SQLite database(tried populating it manually, but it's way to slow). So I decided to use the Cordova-sqlite-storage plugin(https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage). I have a dump file witch opens just fine with no errors, but when I try to fetch anything I get no results. Anyways, here's my code:

In app.js:

```
app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydb", createFromLocation: 1});
    });
})
```

In controllers.js

```
.controller("HomeController", function($scope,Test){
    $scope.test = function(){
        Test.getAlchohol().then(function(res){
            console.log(res.length);
        });
    };
})
```

My db fetching service:

```
.factory('Test', function($cordovaSQLite){
    var arr = [];
    return{
        getAlchohol:function(){
            var query = "SELECT * FROM Alchohol";
            return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res){
                arr = res.rows;
                return arr;
            }, function(err){
                console.error(err);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

And my dump file goes something like this:

```
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;
PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE "Alchohol" (
  "id" int(11) NOT NULL ,
  "intoxication" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "text_id_1" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "text_id_2" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "text_id_3" int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
INSERT INTO "Alchohol" VALUES (1,0,20,21,22);
INSERT INTO "Alchohol" VALUES (2,1,18,19,22);
INSERT INTO "Alchohol" VALUES (3,2,23,24,25);
INSERT INTO "Alchohol" VALUES (4,3,26,24,25);
INSERT INTO "Alchohol" VALUES (5,4,27,28,25);
INSERT INTO "Alchohol" VALUES (6,5,29,30,25);
INSERT INTO "Alchohol" VALUES (7,6,29,31,32);
INSERT INTO "Alchohol" VALUES (8,7,33,31,34);
INSERT INTO "Alchohol" VALUES (9,8,35,31,36);
INSERT INTO "Alchohol" VALUES (10,9,33,31,37);
END TRANSACTION;
```

I've tried every possible solution I found online and nothing worked for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Have you tried to open the database with the file suffix, like: db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydb.db", createFromLocation: 1});

Comment: Yes, but this is what i get

 `0     399896   log      OPEN database: mydb.sqlite

1     399909   log      OPEN database: mydb.sqlite failed, aborting any pending transactions

2     399910   log      Could not open database`

Comment: Two points: Are you sure that it is right to use a dump and not a real sqlite db? And there is a tip in the documentation:  If you don't see the data from the pre-populated database file, completely remove your app and try it again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open prepopulated SQLite dtabase in Cordova (for android) and Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922548/open-prepopulated-sqlite-dtabase-in-cordova-for-android-and-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that [@Joerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165657/joerg) is right and you need to use a [SQLite DB file](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html) to pre-populate the DB with the Cordova-sqlite-storage plugin, not a SQL dump.

You could use [this plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter) to import the SQL dump.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here: [Open prepopulated SQLite dtabase in Cordova (for android) and Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922548/open-prepopulated-sqlite-dtabase-in-cordova-for-android-and-visual-studio/35040103#35040103)

Basically, the plugin you use (https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) doesn't work with pre-populated databases.

However, this one works: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Basically instead of using cordova-plugin-sqlite (deprecated) or cordova-sqlite-storage, just use [cordova-sqlite-ext](https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext) for this.

Check my complete answer for the same problem here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36478499/976948

Comment: Please do not post links to [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

Do some changes.
1. Remove database connection from app.run(). Put that code in factory service

```
    dbConnection :function(){
                if (window.cordova) {
                dbconn = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" , location: 'default'}); 
          $cordovaSQLite.execute(dbconn, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contacts(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, Email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, Phone INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,Website   TEXT,Address TEXT,Notes TEXT,Softdelete INTEGER default 0)");
            }
           else{
           dbconn = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(dbconn, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contacts(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,Email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, Phone INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,Website TEXT,Address TEXT,Notes TEXT,Softdelete INTEGER default 0)");
                                    }
           return dbconn;
        }
```

2. Call your getAlchohol() function on device ready.

   ```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   function onDeviceReady() {
       Test.getAlchohol().then(function(res){
               console.log(res.length);
           });
   }
   ```